# How to test view model with sealed class representing the view state?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I'm trying to create unit test for my view model, basically the view model calls a repository function and then returns its result, and then the viewmodel send the result back to the view but inside a sealed class. I'm testing the view model using the onChanged, so the idea is to verify the first onChanged, it must be Loading, and then the second one must be Photos, and it is partially, because I have to create another Photo sealed class, insert the fake list there and then use the verify, but of course the two results are different, thus of the same type.

How can I test a sequence of view states?

The viewmodel method to be tested:

```
    fun doPhotoRequest(albumId: Long) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = (PhotosViewState.Loading)

            albumsRepository.getPhotos(albumId).let { response ->
                if (response is Response.Success) {
                    _state.value = (PhotosViewState.Photos(response.data.sortedBy { it.title.length }))
                } else {
                    val error = (response as Response.Error).exception.localizedMessage
                    _state.value = (PhotosViewState.Error(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The sealed class

```
sealed class PhotosViewState {
    object Loading : PhotosViewState()
    class Error(val error: String?) : PhotosViewState()
    class Photos(val photos: List<Photo>) : PhotosViewState()
}
```

The test (just the first line is executed without any error)

`verify(viewState, times(1)).onChanged(PhotosViewState.Loading)`
`verify(viewState, times(1)).onChanged(PhotosViewState.Photos(list))`

Comment: Hey, were you able to able to write test for this code, if yes can you share your test please

Comment: Any news? =( I've the same situation

Comment: how did you resolve it?